# Best/efficent way to remember last function result

Tags: javascript, bind

I got used to using `bind` to remember the last result of function and to keep track to be able to use the last result for the next result. For instance to concat or join last string to a new string without using outer variables:

```
function remStr(outStr){

  return function c(lastStr,newStr){

    if(!newStr)return lastStr;

    var all = lastStr+newStr;

    return c.bind(null,all);

  }.bind(null,outStr);

}

var str = remStr('stack');
str = str('over');
str = str('flow');
str(); // stackoverflow
```

The problem is that I want to call `remStr` several times and so `bind` came into play. But can it be done better or just differently, maybe it turns out that for one case an approach fulfills a task better than `remStr`?

Comment: How do you want to call the function? Show it

Comment: You're _completely_ misunderstanding `bind()`.  Read the documentation.

Comment: Can you not use a session variable?

Comment: @Sizons in his case I do not want to. To explain it it would take some time ;)

Comment: @SLaks you are right, I used this approach for objects not string so that's why I used bind but bind should only be used for context issues in the first place. As it was mentioned in the second answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, how about just using the closure?

```js
function remStr(outStr) {
  return function c(newStr) {
    if (!newStr) return outStr;
    outStr += newStr;
    return c;
  }
}

var str = remStr('stack');
str = str('over');
str = str('flow');
str(); // stackoverflow
```

As mentioned by [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) in the comments, JavaScript strings are immutable, so if you intend to use large or many strings, you will probably want to buffer them in an array.

```js
function remStr(outStr) {
  var buffer = [outStr || ''];
  return function c(newStr) {
    if (!newStr) return buffer.join('');
    buffer.push(newStr);
    return c;
  }
}

var str = remStr('stack');
str = str('over');
str = str('flow');
str(); // stackoverflow
```

Comment: Of course a closure is possible, why did I not see it. thanks :)

Comment: @Blauharley FYI JavaScript strings are immutable. Keeping appending to them with `+=` is a comparatively inefficient operation. This approach would benefit from `outStr = [outStr || ""]`, `outStr.push(newStr)` and `return outStr.join("");`

Comment: @Tomalak Good point. I've added some alternate code using as array for the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using `Function.bind` here at all. You can cache the arguments. And then join it.

This approach is widely known as functions are also objects and can have properties. `Function.bind` is used to change the context of the given function and that isn't what we want.

```
function concat(word){
   return function fn(anWord){
       if(!anWord) return fn.words.join("");
       (fn.words || (fn.words = [word])).push(anWord);
   }
}
```

Now you can use it like below:

```
var str = concat("stack");
str("over");
str("flow");
console.log(str()); // "stackoverflow"
```

Comment: @Tomalak both issues have been rectified. Thanks for pointing out.